# AWS Route R53 route www subdomain to apex domain S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have an apex domain set up in Route 53 which has an alias file point to an S3 bucket where my frontend application is hosted.

I want a `www` subdomain to route to this apex domain's S3 bucket, so a user doesn't see the difference between using the naked domain and the `www` subdomain.

I've tried making a second hosted zone with an alias file pointing to the apex domain but that doesn't work or let me.

I also tried to make a second bucket with a `www` subdomain as the name and tried to redirect to the first bucket but it didn't seem to work.

What's the proper way to do this? By what I'm seeing is I should actually create the bucket and the hosted zone using the `www` subdomain then redirect the apex domain to that bucket.

Why must it be this way? 
What's the best practice and low cost AWS way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new record for hostname `www` in the *original* hosted zone, setting Alias to "Yes" pointing to the web site hosting endpoint for the "www" bucket.

Comment: this is after creating a second bucket for `www`?

Comment: this worked! Strange I have to create another S3 bucket to redirect. Why am I not able to simply redirect with Amazon's R53 Service - is it not their DNS service?

Comment: DNS can't do redirects, ever.  A redirect from one hostname to another *always* requires participation of a web server.  Some hosting providers hide this fact by allowing you to "create a redirect" in their "DNS configuration" portal but what they are *actually* doing is creating a DNS record pointing to a fleet of web servers they have set up for exactly that purpose, and configuring the web servers to generate the redirect.  The empty bucket redirect, on its face, may seem silly/inefficient/wasteful/overkill, but it turns out to be an elegant and cost-effective way to handle this use case.

Comment: ahhh okay that makes sense. Is there a way to not just have a redirect? What happens if I want to show `www` subdomain in the URL also? Or would I have to configure the `www` subdomain first and have the naked domain point at that? What's the best practice for this case? (hide naked domains and default to `www`?)

Comment: You need a redirect, one way or the other.  Best practice is *not* to have your content accessible via both names -- search engines don't like that, and it invites potenial problems later.  Whether to prefer the www or the bare domain is mostly a "religious" argument (a matter of opinion/preference, with no objectively correct answer), unless you are using additional subdomains and using cookies -- in which case www may be preferred to keep cookies from the main site cleanly separate from those of any subdomains.  To me, www feels dated and amateurish, and I will usually redirect that to bare.